# $\lim_{x \to 2} x^2+x-1 = 5$ with epsilon-delta

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I've been trying to work through this and got stuck on a step. My professor wrote out a solution but I don't understand it. Would someone help explain what exactly he did?

$|x^2+x-1-5|<\epsilon \impliedby |(x+3)(x-2)|<\epsilon$

Up to this point things make sense to me: we're confirming a limit by searching for a valid $\delta$ (ideally we will find that $|x-2| <$ something involving $\epsilon$). However, my professor suggests the next step to be $|(2+3)^2(x-2)|< \epsilon$, which doesn't make much sense to me. Why did he do this, and what is the reasoning that makes this an appropriate step? Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Basically $\lim_{x\to2} x+3 = 5$ does not **strongly** influence the choice of $\epsilon$, however doing the same thing for $x - 2$ would result in multiplying by 0. Which does not help to find the $\epsilon$

Comment: $$|(x+3)(x-2)|=|x+3||x-2|<(\delta+5)\delta=\epsilon$$

when $|x-2|<\delta$.  This would've been my approach.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: one should avoid the approach you mention. Definition of limit is not supposed to be an exercise in algebraic manipulation of inequalities and in particular one does not solve $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$. See this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2294403/72031 Also your approach will lead to an expression  for $\delta$ involving square roots and that is kind of circular.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Ah, okay.  That does make sense, though its just my way of gaining good intuition.  If I were really going to do this, I'd probably use it to find a simpler form, like $6\delta=\epsilon\forall\delta<1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We compute the limit of $f (x) $ near $a=2$, this means that $x $ is not far away from $2$. So we can assume that the distance from $x $ to $2$ which is $|x-2|$ is for example less than $1$.

thus

$$-1\le x-2\le 1 \tag 1$$
$$\implies 1\le x\le 3$$
$$\implies 4\le x+3 \le 6$$
$$\implies |x+3|\le 6$$
$$\implies |(x+3)(x-2)|\le 6|x-2| \tag 2$$

finally, given $\epsilon>0$,

If $|x-2|\le 1$ and $|x-2|\le \frac {\epsilon}{6} $ then
$|f (x)-f (2)|\le \epsilon $.

We can take $$\eta=\min (1,\frac {\epsilon}{6}) .$$
to satisfy conditions $(1) $ and $(2) $.

Comment: May be, Your Professor assumed that $|x-2|<20$ which gives $|x+3|<25=(2+3)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

We will arbitrarily assume that $\delta\leq 1$ (This is a valid assumption to make since, in general, once we find a $\delta$ that works, all smaller values of $\delta$ also work.). Then  $|x-2|<\delta\leq 1$ implies that $1< x < 3$ so that $4 < x+3| < 6$ it follows that $$|x+3||x-2| < 6|x-2|<\epsilon$$
iff $|x-2|<\frac{\epsilon}{6}$.
Now choose $\delta = \min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{6}\}$ (This guarantees that both assumptions made about $\delta$ in the course of this proof are taken into account simultaneously.).

Answer (score 1):

Your Professor might have made the 'suggestion' to get you to realize there can be different ways to handle epsilon/delta arguments, all equally valid. Sometimes there is no 'formula' to plug into.

When working with epsilon/delta arguments, it starts with

$\forall \epsilon, \; \epsilon \gt 0$

You can change this to

$\forall \epsilon, \; 0 \lt \epsilon \le K$

for any (fixed) positive K, with no harm done.

---

Let $\epsilon$ be any positive number; we can assume that $\epsilon \le 50$

Consider the equation

$|(x+3)| \, |(x−2)| = 50$

Notice that plugging in $7$ for $x$ works.

Explain why choosing $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{10}$ works for this (almost) arbitrarily given $\epsilon$.

Hint: Determine the maximum value of $|x+3|$ on the interval $[2 - \delta, 2 + \delta]$ by using the fact that  $\epsilon \le 50$.

(inequality logic will be provided if requested)